# Did babies nurse in the wilderness?

Tags: baby-infant, dor-hamidbar, mon-manna

We know that the Jews were sustained by the heavenly mun for forty years in the wilderness. They didn't eat anything else, as it provided their every needs. They didn't even produce any bodily waste.

I was wondering, perhaps it's obvious, but did the Jewish babies nurse in the wilderness? Or did they also eat from the mun. It was miraculous food, so perhaps they didn't need to nurse. Or is it simply that they received the nutrients from the mun through their mother's milk.

Comment: Yoma 75b לתינוקות דבש

Comment: I find your question interesting as in Deut. 23:13, the Torah says this: “Designate a place outside the camp where you can go to relieve yourself. As part of your equipment have something to dig with, and when you relieve yourself, dig a hole and cover up your excrement.” Why do you think they didn't produce any bodily waste?

Comment: @AlanDev that's not talking about their forty years in the wilderness

Comment: Is that "40 year" figure not supposed to be a typological number? I mean, walking from Egypt to around Gaza/Ashqelon, even if you wonder around, doesn't take more than a few weeks.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not sure what you mean. Have you ever read the Torah?

Comment: @robev : No need to take that tone. A "typological number" is a number which has symbolic meaning in addition to, or _instead_ of its literal meaning. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529647/word-for-numbers-with-special-meaning-particularly-bible) here on StackExchange for example.

Comment: And about "having read the Torah" - you know well enough that, in Jewish custom, some of the text is interpreted literally and other parts are interpreted symbolically or allegorically.

Comment: @einpoklum I think robev is referring to https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2201/jewish/Shelach-in-a-Nutshell.htm

Comment: @wfb: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rashi (Bamidbar 11:5) explains why the manna did not assume the taste of those items enumerated in that pasuk:
אמר ר' שמעון מפני מה המן משתנה לכל דבר חוץ מאלו מפני שהן קשים למניקות אומרים לאשה אל תאכלי שום ובצל מפני התינוק משל למלך וכו' כדאיתא בספרי.
Since these are bad for nursing, the manna did not assume these flavors. Apparently, then, women did nurse in the wilderness.

Comment: I forgot about this. Thanks